# Solaris + date + what is the same equivalent for Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris, date

on Linux the syntax for date with seconds is:

```
date +%s
1438587288
```

from MAN PAGE -   **%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC**

what is the same equivalent for Solaris?

Comment: With Solaris 11: `date +%s` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Solaris (or any POSIX system), you can use:

```
nawk 'BEGIN{srand(); print srand()}'
```